# Unable to run Spring Boot application: Failed to determine class error

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot throws the following error at the initial step of a project.

I am about to develop a project from scratch. I tried to run the application before writing any code, but the following error pops up.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

2023-06-12T21:33:13.531+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] com.example.food.FoodApplication         : Starting FoodApplication using Java 17.0.3 with PID 10624 (F:\YOU_SEE_ME\food\target\classes started by shaneeqaz in F:\YOU_SEE_ME\food)
2023-06-12T21:33:13.589+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] com.example.food.FoodApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-12T21:33:20.704+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-12T21:33:20.883+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 101 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-12T21:33:24.540+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-12T21:33:24.593+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-12T21:33:24.593+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-12T21:33:25.110+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-12T21:33:25.113+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11045 ms
2023-06-12T21:33:25.481+05:30  WARN 10624 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-06-12T21:33:25.486+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-12T21:33:25.601+05:30  INFO 10624 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-12T21:33:25.668+05:30 ERROR 10624 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My pom.xml file which I generated from start.spring.io is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>food</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>food</name>
    <description>Food Ordering</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Further, I noticed that I am getting the same error for existing Spring Boot projects, which were running fine last time.

Much appreciated if you let me know if any environment variables got deleted/modified.

***Note**: I am a beginner to Spring Boot*

Comment: *Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.* I think the message is clear. You hav to configure the url for the database you want to use or add a h2 driver to your project

Comment: I wonder who dared downvote that beginner question. That's really unfair. I upvoted it, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are expected to specify what database you're willing to connect to, in your `application.properties` file, for example:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDatabase
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
username=postgres
password=postgres
port=5432
```